# SSL error when restarting application

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, ssl, activex, indy

The application is a trusted ActiveX container which needs to support SSL for connections to a third-party service.

That works fine, except in a specific situation:
If you keep IE open with another tab, close the page with the active x control, then browse to the page with the active x control on it again, when that control tries to set up SSL again, it fails with "Error Creating SSL Context".

Reading other threads on this error leads me to think that I may somehow need to reuse the SSL context instead of setting up a new context. That or close the SSL context properly when the active x control is closed. The error doesn't happen if you restart IE.

More information - we are using Codegear RAD Studio 2007, with the Indy library for SSL. This problem only happens when the active x does the initial log in or validation call through ssl, then sets up another ssl connection to retrieve data from an API. This connection is disposed of, then the active x control is closed down. It is when the control tries to log in again that we receive the error "Error creating ssl context".

Comment: That error means OpenSSL's `SSL_CTX_new()` function is failing. Contexts are not shared across connections, Indy creates a new context each per connection. It is rare that `SSL_CTX_new()` itself would fail, unless OpenSSL itself hasn't been initialized correctly, or you are sharing an `SSLIOHandler` object across multiple Indy client components, or something like that. Indy should already be closing the context when the I/O is destroyed. That being said, you are using old versions of Delphi and Indy, so you might also consider upgrading (at least Indy) and see if the problem still continues.

Comment: Thank you Remy. The problem ended up disappearing when some build parameters were changed(when I was trying to debug the delphi code) and some new directories were included in a project. So it might be a build thing.